# is ml.net can be integrated with .net framework version 4.7?

Tags: .net-4.8, ml.net

when I searched in google, it is saying that it's possible, but when I searched it in chatgpt, it is saying it's not possible.

I'm little confused now, if it is possible can you guide me the right version of this package Microsoft.ML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with Microsoft.ML, but by simply looking at NuGet, it shows that it supports .NET Framework, .NET Standard and .NET as seen here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML/#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Microsoft is targeting .NET Standard 2.0 which is a formal specification of the .NET APIs implemented by nearly all versions of .NET. You can find more details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0